# Create new column in Pandas that describes all elements in list column

Tags: python, pandas, list, replace

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1, 2, 3, 4], 
"item":[[22, 78], [78], [78,79], [78,456,254]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"IDs":[1,2], [3], [1,3,4], [3,4]}
```

and desired output is `df2` with an extra column with all the items in 1 list describing the `"ID"` elements. Ideally without duplicates and ordered by descending number of appearance:

```
 df2 = pd.DataFrame({"IDs":[1,2], [3], [1,3,4], [3,4],
"all_items":[78,22], [78], [78,79,22,456,254], [78,79,456,254]}
```

I am guessing I should use `.append()` for adding a new "all_items" column and for loop with `.replace()` in first steps. I just cannot figure out, how it works with the list column in Pandas. I would be grateful for the solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `explode`  + `map` then `groupby`  get the `unique` value

```
df2['new'] = df2['IDs'].explode().map(dict(zip(df1['ID'],df1['item']))).explode().groupby(level=0).unique()
df2
Out[47]: 
         IDs                     new
0     [1, 2]                [22, 78]
1        [3]                [78, 79]
2  [1, 3, 4]  [22, 78, 79, 456, 254]
3     [3, 4]      [78, 79, 456, 254]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! However, lists in new column appear like this: array([22, 78, 79, 456, 254, dtype=object). Any idea why or better how to make it look just like: [22, 78, 79, 456, 254]? Thanks! :)